# Python: roots of negative (invalid value encountered in power)

Tags: python, math, matplotlib

I make the following code to graph root function:

```
import pylab
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def roots(minimo=-5, maximo=5, step=1, potencia=3):
    rootsLs=[]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    valor =1.0/potencia
    for i in np.arange(minimo,maximo,step):
        rootsLs.append((i)**valor)
    pylab.plot(rootsLs)
    left,right = ax.get_xlim()
    low,high = ax.get_ylim()
    grid()
    #pylab.show()
    return rootsLs
```

But, when I try to compute the cube root of negative numbers Idle warns

`Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/media/bidone/calculus/grahphRoots.py", line 18
    rootsLs.append((i)**valor)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power`

For a calling with default values (cube roots, range from -5 to 5), the list returned is `[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0, 1.0, 1.2599210498948732, 1.4422495703074083, 1.5874010519681994]`.
But when I evaluate, *vg*., `-4**(1.0/3)` in the idle shell it does not complain and return the correct answer, `-1.5874010519681994`.

What's wrong?

Comment: python is treating the '-' as a separate thing from the '4', in testing you can put (-4)**(1.0/3) and it should show you what you expect

Comment: @JamesTobin , knowing the fact that "_python is treating the '-' as a separate thing from the '4'_" I have fixed my code.

Answer (score 2):

```
-4**(1.0/3)
```

is evaluated as

```
-( 4**(1.0/3) )
```

so the power resp. root is of a positive number. Allow complex numbers to compute

```
>>> import cmath

>>> (-4+0j)**(1.0/3)
(0.7937005259840999+1.3747296369986024j)
```

Note that the general rule is to return the root with the smallest (positive) angle, conforming with the computation method

```
pow(x,y) = exp(y*Ln(x))
```

where for complex numbers

```
Ln(z) = ln(abs(z)) + i*arg(z)
arg(a+i*b) = atan2(b,a)
```

Answer (score 0):

According the information give by James Tobin, I have remake my code in such way that it seams to works correctly with all the inputs I have give until now.
The new code is the following:

```
import pylab
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def roots(minimo=-5, maximo=5, step=1, potencia=3):
    rootsLs=[]
    color=['m','g','r','b']
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    valor =1.0/potencia
    ranging = np.arange(minimo,maximo,step)
    for i in ranging:
        if i < 0:
            i = i * (-1)
            point = -1*(i**valor)
        else:
            point = i**valor
        rootsLs.append(point)
    pylab.plot(ranging, rootsLs)
    grid()
    pylab.show()
```

Insert a `if` statement to get the absolute value of the negative inputs and then converting it back to negative after exponentiation has solved the problem.